# I was hacked, I have the hacker's email

Tags: account-security, facebook

My Facebook was hacked, and it has no recovery options, however I accidentally got the hacker's email.

Comment: There is no question here. If you want to know how to recover your account, then that's a question for Facebook. If you want to somehow attack the hacker, then that's not what we do here.

Answer (score 1):

The hacker's email is probably a burner so most likely quite useless to you.

If you are able to login to your Facebook account, change the password immediately and activate 2fa. Use a random and long password and unique for every account. And use a password manager.

If you are not able to get in your Facebook account. Create a new account and notify all your relatives via a secure way about the situation.

Depending on your country and your specific situation you might want to notify the police. Sometimes police has a specific online security department.